# Transform a data frame so multiple, overlapping columns form a single scale?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

Say I have a data frame as follows (in reality this is multiple data frames bound):

```
data.frame(
  position = c(3,4,7,12,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  colb = c(1,3,8,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  colc = c(4,6,9,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  position = c(2,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,19,21,24,26),
  colb = c(1,3,8),
  colc = c(4,6,9)
)
```

(Sorry, gets flagged if I post the data format myself.)

How can I transform this so I have a unified system of indicating a 'position'? ie one of the two formats below.

A single column scale:

```
position    colb colc   colb.1 colc.1
1            NA  NA      NA     NA
2            NA  NA      1      4
3            1    4      NA     NA
4            3    6      NA     NA
5            NA   NA     NA     NA
6            NA   NA     NA     NA
7            8    9      3      6
8            NA   NA     8      9
9            NA   NA     NA     NA
10           NA   NA     1      4
11           NA   NA     3      6
12           2    5      8      9
13           NA   NA     NA     NA
14           NA   NA     NA     NA
15           NA   NA     1      4
16           NA   NA     3      6
17           NA   NA     NA     NA
18           NA   NA     NA     NA
19           NA   NA     8      9
20           NA   NA     NA     NA
21           NA   NA     1      4
22           NA   NA     NA     NA
23           NA   NA     NA     NA
24           NA   NA     3      6
25           NA   NA     NA     NA
26           NA   NA     8      9
```

Or with separate columns, but 'matching':

```
position colb colc position.1 colb.1 colc.1
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        2       3      6
3        1    4         NA      NA     NA
4        3    6         NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
7        8    9         7       1      4
NA       NA   NA        8       3      6
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        10      1      4
NA       NA   NA        11      3      6
12       2   5          12      8      9
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        15      8      9
NA       NA   NA        16      1      4
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        19      1      4
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        21      8      9
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        24      8      9
NA       NA   NA        NA      NA     NA
NA       NA   NA        26      8      9
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `df` contains the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
  position = c(3,4,7,12,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  colb = c(1,3,8,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  colc = c(4,6,9,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  position = c(2,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,19,21,24,26),
  colb = c(1,3,8),
  colc = c(4,6,9)
)

df1 <- df[,1:3]
df2 <- df[,4:6]

names(df2) <- c("position", "colb", "colc")

df_out <- rbind(df1, df2)

df_out <- df_out[!is.na(df_out$position),]
df_out <- df_out[order(df_out$position),]
df_out
```